# javascript convert double quotes into single quote in a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a string which contains mix of single and double quotes. [You can see here](http://jsfiddle.net/UdNBu/2/). First, If i try to make the jquery object of that string, i get break up of href and it's page link. both parts behave like attributes of tag with an additional double quote attached with page's link part. like console of $(mystr)= ... href="" display.aspx""" where display.aspx is page's link. but if when i try href=\'display.aspx\', i'm able to get expected output. How do i get rid of this partition of attribute problem? code given on jsfiddle is

```
var s= "<tr role=\"row\" id=\"1\" tabindex=\"-1\" class=\"ui-widget-content jqgrow ui-row-ltr\"><td role=\"gridcell\" style=\"\" title=\"Albania\" aria-describedby=\"mytabl_Country\">Albania</td><td role=\"gridcell\" style=\"text-align:center;\" title=\"\" aria-describedby=\"mytabl_Nutrition related\"><img class=\"resultsGridImage\" src=\"Images/check.png\" oldtitle=\"Click on reference ID to view details:<ol><li>ID: <a target=\'_blank\' href=\"DisplayRefmat.aspx?NOPAID=241\">241</a>, Analyses of the situation and national action plan on food and nutrition for Albania 2003-2008</li> <li>ID: <a target=\'_blank\' href=\"DisplayRefmat.aspx?NOPAID=826\">826</a>, Towards a healthy country with healthy people - Public health and health promotion strategy</li> <li>ID: <a target=\'_blank\' href=\"DisplayRefmat.aspx?NOPAID=827\">827</a>, Analyses of the State of Food and Nutrition in Albania</li> <li>ID: <a target=\'_blank\' href=\"DisplayRefmat.aspx?NOPAID=828\">828</a>, Recommendation on healthy nutrition in Albania</li> </ol>\"></td></tr>";
console.debug($(s));
$('#btable').append(s);
```

Comment: what are you trying to do, you are opening an ordered list inside an image tag (without closing the image tag by the way), why?

Comment: the ending double quote with closing > i.e( \"></td></tr>";) in the string is supposed to close the image tag. and image tag has oldtitle='orderedlist' in it required by plugin. it works in other browsers except i.e 9 and ff's latest version. i need to stop breakup of href attribute and it's url value.

Comment: <img src="" > is not a closed image tag, close it with / like <img src="" />, I'll see if I can find a solution to your problem

Comment: the img src has tag properly enclosed in the table where this data is retrieved from. after getting data with $('thesourcetable').html(), it looses the forward slash(/) and shows only double quotes. i think regex can be used to inject forward slash. but problem here is not 'i guess' because of ending img src properly. i think this problem needs not to use $(table).html() to retrieve data. some other way needs to be found to avoid this problem. thanks for your cooperation @DaniëlTulp.

Comment: sorry, can't seem to find a solution, perhaps another angle of attack is better, another way to get the same functionality?

Comment: i resolved it just by converting double quotes to single quotes and where it was creating problem, i removed quotes. it's ok now in all browsers. this change wasn't effective in the source table , rather i did this in the plugin just before rendering. ur efforts got points. thanks

Comment: you are welcome. glad i did manage to help you solve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

perhaps I'm thinking to simplistic here, but this pops in mind when I look at the above code:

```
var s= "<tr role=\"row\" id=\"1\"....</tr>";
```

can be written as

```
var s= "<tr role='row' id='1'...</tr>";
```

why use double quotes in your string?

Comment: the string contains double quotes because this string is made by using $(anothertable).html(), i tried to get single quoted string but couldn't. and secondly original string doesn't contain escape( \") rather ("double quotes) only. it's same as u wrote, i had to use escape to run this code in jsfiddle.